# How to create a folder outside the poject directory in rust

Tags: rust, directory

I using rust to create a folder in `~`, however when my code runs the directory is created inside my project's folder instead in `~`.

My code:

```rust
use std::fs::create_dir_all;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let path = Path::new("~/.hidden_folder");
    match create_dir_all(path) {
        Ok(f) => {
            println!("created folder")
        },
        Err(err) => {
            println!("{:?}", err);
        }
    };
}
```

Any idea how to create the folder in the correct directory ?

Comment: Which os are you using?

Comment: `~` isn't a real folder or link, it's just a thing expanded by your shell. If you want your application to support that, you have to do it yourself, or use a library to do it for your.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your home directory, I recommend using [this crate](https://docs.rs/dirs/3.0.2/dirs/fn.home_dir.html) or specifying the absolute path. If you want to save it in any other directories, just use relative or absolute paths, but don't use `~` because Rust doesn't know the context of `~`.